# Permission denied (publickey) Git and AWS EC2

Tags: linux, git, ssh, amazon-ec2

There are many similar questions and answers related to this authorization issue --- "Permission denied (publickey)". However, none of them works for my problem...

Here is my situation: I am using Amazon web server EC2 and my PC connects well with the server. For the next step, I was trying to install git on the server. The result which I was hoping to accomplish is updating the server-end when I push from local. But here the problem showed up: "Permission denied (publickey)"

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.68.24.4 [52.68.24.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 52.68.24.4:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ieQEskLZ3tiW76F5KPhlQfHcGYFW+SifiIDQnBUZHmY
debug1: Host '52.68.24.4' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/IvyLin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

One thing I am wondering is where should I put the public key exactly? There is one .ssh file for "validate server connection" already in the server, path: `~/.ssh` and it works for me. 
In terms of the ssh key for git, I created another .ssh folder inside the git folder, path: `~/home/git/.ssh`. Which file does it look for during the connection? Though I've tried to put the public key into `~/.ssh`, but still, it does not work...

I've been stuck there for so long time and really appreciated if someone can help me out! Workarounds to achieving "update as push" will also help me out!

Comment: What is the name of the file containing your key?

Comment: for storing public keys in the server end, it is '~/.ssh/ authorized_keys'@Jakuje

Comment: No, in your local computer. If you stored it on your own on the server, make sure that the permissions on `ls -l ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

> One thing I am wondering is where should I put the public key exactly?

you have to put the public key on your git server under your account.

> Which file does it look for during the connection?

you have to copy the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your git server account

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying! I have put the public key into the '~/.ssh/authorized_keys' on the server side, but still, it gives the error... Any other possibilities for it to go wrong? Actually, if both keys are supposed to be put under the server account, does it mean they can be merged into one? Or we need config files to distinguish them... I am getting confused...

Comment: you need to distinguish and use the config file